# How to determine URL with search query filled in

Tags: html, url, search, hyperlink

I am trying to make a hyperlink to embed in a pdf report I am sending out to my company. For example I use multiple carriers and put in the container number for tracking field and hit search. I would like the url to the direct results page. How do I achieve this?

Website https://www.hamburgsud-line.com/liner/en/liner_services/ecommerce/visibility/track_trace/index.html

Tracking SUDU1335271

Comment: It doesn't look like the website is designed to have a URL for that.  It submits the data for that form with the POST method from AJAX.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.  Rather it is a question about using your website.